# Vue.js raise an error when view data in wrong case

Tags: time, error-handling, vue.js, case

I have the following template:

```
<template>
<div>
    <h1>Users from SQL Server!</h1>

    <p>This component demonstrates fetching data from the server.</p>

    <table v-if="userlist.length" class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>First</th>
                <th>Last</th>
                <th>Date</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <!-- nb: These items must match the case they are passed in with (the Json passed back from .net Core serialises to lowerCamelCase) otherwise they will 
            show nothing and no error is raised! -->
        <tr v-for="item in userlist">
            <td>{{ item.userid }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.firstname }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.lastname }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.createdonDate }}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <p v-else><em>Loading...</em></p>
</div>
```

This displays a table with no data. This is because the data passed in from the server has a different case to that used in the template items. If I fix them for example:

```
item.userId
item.firstName
item.lastName
item.createdOnDate
```

Then it works and data is displayed. The issue for me is that no error is returned. I am learning Vue using the .Net Core SPA template as a starter. But it took me a while to realise what I was doing wrong. If this was a model in the razor view it would have blown with a helpful error.

Is there a way to raise an error for this kind of thing?

I do have the Chrome Vue extension installed and realised the problem when I looked at the data there. But I was stumped for a while.

[image]

**UPDATE 1:**  Thanks @ndpu for your solution but I am having trouble fitting it into my project.  I have a boot.ts file like this:

```
import 'bootstrap';
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

Vue.use((VueRouter) as any);

Vue.config.devtools = true;

const routes = [
{ path: '/', component: require('./components/home/home.vue.html') },
{ path: '/counter', component: 
require('./components/counter/counter.vue.html') },
{ path: '/fetchdata', component: 
require('./components/fetchdata/fetchdata.vue.html') },
{ path: '/users', component: require('./components/users/users.vue.html') },
{ path: '/user', component: require('./components/user/user.vue.html') }
];


new Vue({
    el: '#app-root',
    router: new VueRouter({ mode: 'history', routes: routes }),
    render: h => h(require('./components/app/app.vue.html'))
});
```

Where do I put the `Object.prototype.safeGet`? In there or in my component templates? Nowhere seems to work.

**UPDATE 2:**

I got it to work by putting the code from @ndpu into app.ts like this:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import { Component } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component({
    components: {
        MenuComponent: require('../navmenu/navmenu.vue.html')
    }
})
export default class AppComponent extends Vue {
}

Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'safeGet', {
    get: function () {
        return this;
    }
});
```

Comment: Not really. Javascript doesn't have any typing so you won't get back the error messages you are used to in C#. You could potentially validate the objects against expected properties after the come down from the server potentially, depending on how you retrieve the data.

Comment: Thanks Bert. I guess I naively thought that with using Typescript and a framework like Vue there might be a way defending against this kind of issue.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know of anyone doing template typing at this point. React has a better use case for that. I'm not sure what's going on in Angular2 with respect to types in templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Simplest way**: define additional property to `Object` with getter that will only return himself.

```
/* eslint no-extend-native: ["error", { "exceptions": ["Object"] }] */

Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'safeGet', {
    get: function () {             
        return this;
    }
});
```

So, by adding `safeGet` to any data attribute, you can be sure that you will get `TypeError` if attribute is undefined:

this:

```
<td>{{ item.userid.safeGet }}</td>
```

will produce exception (if actual property name is userId):

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'safeGet' of undefined
```

### ***FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/yMv7y/2785/***

---

Also, you can define simple method in object prototype to check property existence:

**UPDATE: i couldn't make it work in 'complex' application with modules, webpack etc - vue trying to make added to `Object.prototope` method *reactive*. Didnt know why it is work in simple case like in applied fiddle.**

```
Object.prototype.safeGet = function() {
    var val, args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    var currLvlObj = this;
    for (var i=0; i < args.length; i++) {
        val = currLvlObj = currLvlObj? currLvlObj[args[i]] : undefined;
        if (val === undefined)  {
            throw Error('property with name ' + args[i] + ' is undefined');
        }
    }
    return val;
}
```

and use it like this:

```
<td>{{ item.safeGet('userid') }}</td>
```

this call should throw error (if actual property name is `userId`): `Error: property with name userid is undefined`

PS: nested objects properties can be accessed by passing all property names as arguments. For example, to access 'userId' in `{'data': {'userId': 0}}`:

```
<td>{{ item.safeGet('data', 'userid') }}</td>
```

***FIDDLE***: http://jsfiddle.net/yMv7y/2778/

Comment: Thanks very much. I have updated my question since that's the only place I can add more code. Struggling to fit it into my project.

Comment: Thanks @ndpu. That works if I put the code in my component template. But it's not really ideal. The error message is not very helpful and I'd need it defined in a single place and not in every component.

Comment: I think in reality just getting used to and being aware of this issue is enough.  Logging the data object to the console in dev in my component's .ts file will enable me to quickly check when data doesn't show up. But thanks so much for your answer. It's great learning for me.

Comment: @NorbertNorbertson you can place that code in separate js module and import it in main.js or place it right off in main.js vue module...